# Mongo C# driver 2.0 - Empty result when using object type in search

Tags: c#, mongodb

I had to attach image to make it more clear but "SO says I need 10 reputation to post images", so I'll try to make it clear with just text.

I push data in Mongo using

```
BsonDocument doc = new BsonDocument();
object val = GetValue(); //brings some value like int, string, float etc...
doc.Add("Code", val.ToBson()); //Edited after posting the answer.
```

When the above it saved to Mongo it looks like the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55dac7b1a695e914a4cb6bb7"),
    "Code" : {
    "_t" : "System.Decimal",
    "_v" : "1002"
}
```

Now when I want to query it back I am just using

```
object i = 1002;
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Code", i.ToBson());
var list = this.mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument> ("MyDocuments").Find(filter).ToListAsync().Result;
```

I am getting a empty list back, instead of the result which I saved. Any idea how to query when something is stored as _t and _v ?

Comment: The reason there is the repuation ban on images is because we want text and not screenshots. Also, try to pick titles that are about your question/problem. The current title is pretty vague to say the least. How about my choice for a "little" more descriptive.

Comment: Have you tried using `object i = 1002m;` instead? That way you'd be comparing `decimal` values instead of comparing an `int` with a `decimal`. As an aside, I can't see where an image would be useful in this question - if the image would just be a screenshot *of* text, it's better as it is.

Comment: @BlakesSeven True, I was in a haste to post it. Sorry about that.

Comment: @JonSkeet I fixed it by using ToBsonDocument() API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out that instead of val.ToBson() I should been using val.ToBsonDocument() API. It works fine with the later.